# React: Muuri-react generate random items error - Uncaught Invariant: Invariant failed: The item has not been setted yet

Tags: reactjs

The [muuri-react](https://codesandbox.io/s/muuri-react-grid-forked-il5qo?file=/index.js) demonstrates to generate and add random items.

There was a small modification on the codes to randomly generate 3 items rather than adding 3 more random items. When I modified in codepen and ran it, the items could render successfully. However, when I tried it in a local machine, it couldn't.

When I clicked the "Generate item" button, nothing was appearing on the div, and after the second click, an error message "Uncaught Invariant: Invariant failed: The item has not been setted yet at invariant" shown on the console.

Could anyone tell me what goes wrong?

The following is the code:

````
import { useFilter, generateItems, options } from "./utils";
import { MuuriComponent } from "muuri-react";
import './style.css'

function MuuriDemo() {
    const [items, setItems] = useState(generateItems());

    const Item = ({ color, width, height, title, remove }) => {
        console.log(color);
        return (
            <div className={`item h${height} w${width} ${color}`}>
                <div className="item-content">
                    <div className="card">
                        <div className="card-title">{title}</div>
                        <div className="card-remove">
                            <i className="material-icons" onMouseDown={remove}>
                                &#xE5CD;
                  </i>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    };

    // Children.
    const children = items.map(({ id, color, title, width, height }) => (
        <Item
            key={id}
            color={color}
            title={title}
            width={width}
            height={height}
        />
    ));

    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={() => setItems(generateItems())}>Generate item</button>
            <section className="grid-demo">
            
            <MuuriComponent
                {...options}
                propsToData={({ color, title }) => ({ color, title })}
            >
                {children}
            </MuuriComponent>
            </section>
            
        </div>
    )
}

export default MuuriDemo```
````

Comment: It managed to show what I want if i used react-dom render, is it a correct way?

Comment: I had the same problem. The reason was I was using React 17 that is not compatible with muuri-react @ 3.1.6

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to get it works via the following code. I have no idea whether it is a standard way.

```
import { generateItems, options } from "./utils";
import { MuuriComponent } from "muuri-react";
import './style.css'
import {  render } from "react-dom";

function MuuriDemo() {
    const [items, setItems] = useState(generateItems());

    const Item = ({ color, width, height, title, remove }) => {
        console.log(color);
        return (
            <div className={`item h${height} w${width} ${color}`}>
                <div className="item-content">
                    <div className="card">
                        <div className="card-title">{title}</div>
                        <div className="card-remove">
                            <i className="material-icons" onMouseDown={remove}>
                                &#xE5CD;
                  </i>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    };

    // Children.
    const children = items.map(({ id, color, title, width, height }) => (
        <Item
            key={id}
            color={color}
            title={title}
            width={width}
            height={height}
        />
    ));

    useEffect(() => {
        render(<div>
            <button onClick={() => setItems(generateItems())}>Generate item</button>
            <section className="grid-demo">
                <MuuriComponent
                    {...options}
                    propsToData={({ color, title }) => ({ color, title })}
                >
                    {children}
                </MuuriComponent>
            </section></div>, document.getElementById('muuri'))
        console.log(children);
    }, [children])

    return (
        <div id='muuri'/>
    )
}

export default MuuriDemo
```